# HashMap element is removed when another HashMap name remove an element

Tags: java, hashmap

`appearList` is a HashMap with fixed data. I do:

```
randomPersonList = appearList;
```

Then, when I remove an element from `randomPersonList`, that element on `appearList` is also removed unexpectedly. I expect to keep `appearList` as original.

Can anyone tell me why and how to correct my code?

```
package personaltries;

import java.util.*;

public class issue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, String> appearList = new HashMap<>();
        appearList.put(1,"a");
        appearList.put(2,"b");
        HashMap<Integer, String> randomPersonList = appearList;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean keepPlaying = true;
        while (keepPlaying) {
            System.out.println("1. Pick randomly a person");
            int chosenOption = scanner.nextInt();
            if (chosenOption == 1) {
                pickRandomlyAPerson(randomPersonList, appearList);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong option");
            }
        }

    }
    private static String pickRandomlyAPerson(HashMap<Integer, String> randomPersonList, HashMap<Integer, String> appearList) {
        if(randomPersonList.size()==0){
            randomPersonList=appearList;
        }
        List<Integer> listKey = new ArrayList<>(randomPersonList.keySet());
        int randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(listKey.size());
        int randomNumber = listKey.get(randomIndex);
        String name  = randomPersonList.get(randomNumber);
        randomPersonList.remove(randomNumber);
        System.out.println(name+" please!");
        System.out.println(randomPersonList);
        return (name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HashMap<Integer, String> randomPersonList = appearList;
```

makes randomPersonList the reference to the same object as appearList. So with both variables you are accessing the same object. Either create two HashMaps or create a `clone`.

Answer (score 2):

randomPersonList and appearList are reference to same Map internally.

So when you remove element from one, change is reflected in other as well. Since underlying both are pointing to same object

If you want randomPersonList to be separate what you can do is:

> HashMap<Integer, String> randomPersonList= new HashMap<>(appearList);

This will create a new HashMap with data from appearList

Answer (score 0):

You are doing shallow copy which means both `randomPersonList` and `appearList` point to same reference. You need to perform deep copy by using `putAll()` method or iteration to ensure both hash maps are different references.